# How chrome extension can detach a title in some pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to let my extension detect on some class or some href in inspect page for code example

```
<div role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-cellid="uniqueKey" class="c01414 c01419" style="grid-column: 2 / auto; border: 0px; padding: 0px;"><a tabindex="-1" id="passwordWebsitelink_0" class="c01438 c01439 c01156" href="https://www.1112.com/signup" title="1112.com">1112.com</a></div>
```

from the above. I need to get the title element to my js file something likes

```
var myTitle = document.getelementbyTitle("????");
```

In ???? What text should I replace or do I have to use another way to make it?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question well,
But if your problem is like getting the elements that meets a certain "title" attribute you just have to use querySelectorAll method with this syntax:
document.querySelectorAll('[Attribute = Value]').
In your specific case:
document.querySelectorAll('[title = ???]')

Comment: I'm sorry for the hard to understanding of my question. I'm new on this Stackoverflow. My question means "How can I make my extension get the string value in html tag named "title" by clicking some button on that page, for the example when I clicked the eye button on my password then it get the value of title html tag on my js" I don't know is it clear enough because I'm really new on this. lol

Comment: Did you really mean the word "detach"? Detect?

Comment: Oh yes I'm sorry for a wrong word

Comment: when you have targeted the right element, his title attribute (if it have it!) can be retrieved with: var myTitle = element.getAttribute('title') or more simply var myTitle = element.title